# Elastic: No Persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy elastic in one of ec2 kubernetes master server, I have used following helm chart.

https://helm.elastic.co

with 3 pods and also created a service- Loadbalancer.

My pods are in pending state, when I checked pod's status, i am getting following error.

Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message

---

Warning  FailedScheduling  2m12s (x57 over 82m)  default-scheduler  running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "elasticsearch-master-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Can any one help me in this?

Am beginner in kubernetes.

My EC2 server is: t2 medium

Comment: first thing that you could is check your cluster storage class using kubectl get sc and check how to pass it to the helm chart

Comment: I have 3 pods running, no one has volume, capacity, access modes and storage class assigned

Comment: please, check if the pvc are using your cluster storageclass: When none of the static PVs the administrator created match a user's PersistentVolumeClaim, the cluster may try to dynamically provision a volume specially for the PVC. This provisioning is based on StorageClasses: the PVC must request a storage class and the administrator must have created and configured that class for dynamic provisioning to occur. Claims that request the class "" effectively disable dynamic provisioning for themselves.